# Router as AP on existing network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-access-point

Need help how to convert some old router as AP. The router is Dlink 600 B5E.

In my office we have a wired network and WiFi but with very weak singal. I would like to use this old router and connect it to the wired network.

The network is: MicroTik router-Ubiquity AP (50Mbit/s) and the other one is classic router (10Mbit/s).

I was reading about this over the Internet and just need instructions because I don't want to mess things up with if it possible to make some conflict with the existing network.

Comment: Make sure you connect the network to a LAN port, not the WAN, and everything should be fine. Also, give the router an IP address inside the network so you can manage the router, but make sure it falls outside of the DHCP scope of the other router so it doesn't cause for conflicts.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer! I've done it this way: Interent settings- NAT is on, Internet connection type is DHCP. Wireless is enabled and secured. Network (LAN) the ip addres of the router Dlink 600 is changed to 192.168.150.100 because the main MicroTik is 192.168.150.1 (hope this is ok). Now, do i have to disable or enable DHCP?

Comment: I've posted you an answer, answering the questions you've asked. :)

Comment: Also, it is possible that the Router's throughput is 10Mbit/s, while the switch itself can deal up to 100Mbit. If this is the case, you will get the 50Mbit/s from the MikroTik too, where of course the WiFi may slow things down a bit.

Comment: The valid range would be 150.2 - 150.253, put the second router at 150.254

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you connect the network to a LAN port, not the WAN, and everything should be fine. Also, give the router an IP address inside the network so you can manage the router, but make sure it falls outside of the DHCP scope of the other router so it doesn't cause for conflicts.

When the WAN port is not in use, the internal Router part will not do anything. So port forwarding rules do not apply.

You will want to disable the buildin DHCP server.

Because the router part is bypassed, NAT is not being used. Having it on or off makes no difference, so turn it off if you can. The same goes for any setting related to the WAN port (internet connectivity). As long as it is entered, it should work. So DHCP enabled is fine, or a static non-existent IP address that is outside of the range of your LAN scope will work too.

Comment: If you have an option to turn the firewall/NAT off, do it! No reason to dedicate memory to something not in use!

Comment: I dont understand this part: give the router an IP address inside the network so you can manage the router, but make sure it falls outside of the DHCP scope of the other router. The MicroTik is 192.168.150.1 subnet is 255.255.255.0. Gues the range for hosts is from 150.2-150.254 right? what IP should i need for my second router?

Comment: Your MikroTik has a DHCP range. If you have the router inside this DHCP scope, it will one day get an IP conflict with another device from inside the MikroTik. To prevent that from happening, look at the DHCP range on the MikroTik and ensure that the router falls outside of its range. Edit the DHCP scope if necessary. If you have a range of 192.168.100.50-192.168.100.250, place the router either in the range x.x.x.2-x.x.x.49 or x.x.x.251-x.x.x.254. If your DHCP range is x.x.x.2 - x.x.x.254, then you need to modify that range to x.x.x.3 so the router can be 192.168.100.2

Comment: @Tim_Stewart good suggestion. Edited.

Comment: Many thanks! I will post answer wen i get thinks done.

Comment: @Baz If *this* answer is helpful you should accept it. There's no point in posting another answer unless it's fundamentally different.

Comment: @MichaelBay I agree, but reading Baz's posts, I think his English is not that good and that he merely meant to write: I'll test this information and see if it answers my question, then come back here.